# How can we store these dates into another dataframe as we loop through?

Tags: r, dataframe, loops

In R (studio), I have tried so many iterations of storing just the dates into the turning_point_dates data frame, but I have only been able to get it to store the loop numbers. I can print out each date as it is found, but not able to store them yet.

```
dates = data.frame(Date = seq(from = as.Date("2002-06-01"), to = as.Date("2011-09-30"), by = 'day'))
   
nums = c(98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107)
dataframe_of_numbers = data.frame(nums)    

mat = matrix(ncol=0, nrow=0)
turning_point_dates = data.frame(mat)

for (i in 1:nrow(dataframe_of_numbers)){
   print(dates$Date[dataframe_of_numbers[i,]])
   turning_point_dates[i,] = dates$Date[dataframe_of_numbers[i,]]
}

turning_point_dates
```

How can I instead store the actual dates that are being looped over into the turning_point_dates data frame?

turning_point_dates puts out a data frame looking like the following:
Description:df [10 x 0]

```
1               
2               
3               
4               
5               
6               
7               
8               
9               
10              
1-10 of 10 rows
```

When I want instead a data frame like so:

```
"2002-09-06"
"2002-09-07"
"2002-09-08"
"2002-09-09"
"2002-09-10"
"2002-09-11"
"2002-09-12"
"2002-09-13"
"2002-09-14"
"2002-09-15"
```

Comment: Could you be a bit clearer about what you're trying to do? Also, that code won't run as written because `as.Date("20011-09-31")` throws an error.

Comment: I made some edits to be more clear, and fix the mistakes so it can now run. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit unclear, but if you want to end up with a smaller dataframe that only has the dates corresponding to the row numbers in `nums`, you don't need to use a loop. You can just subset the data frame with `num`, as shown below.

I'm also suggesting using a `tibble` instead of a basic `data.frame`, because subsetting a `tibble` returns a tibble but subsetting a `data.frame` returns a vector.

```
library(tibble)

dates <- tibble::tibble(Date = seq(from = as.Date("2002-06-01"), 
                                   to = as.Date("2011-09-30"), 
                                   by = 'day'))

nums <- c(98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107)

dates_subsetted <- dates[nums,]
```

It can also be done with a loop, but in my view it's much clunkier. It will almost certainly be much, much slower if you have a lot of data.

But since it was asked:

```
library(dplyr)
# set up another tibble for the values we'll extract
dates_looped <- tibble::tibble()

# loop through each row of the input, add that row if 
for (i in 1:nrow(dates)){
  if (i %in% nums) {
    dates_looped <- dplyr::bind_rows(dates_looped, dates[i,])
  }  
}
```

`dates_looped` and `dates_subsetted` are the same, but making `dates_subsetted` took a single line of code that will run many times faster.

Comment: Oh, nice, thank you. This works well :) Can it even be done in a loop though? I would still like to know how. Thanks.

Comment: It can be done, but it's faster and easier to use vector subsetting in R. I've updated the answer to give you an idea.

Comment: Thank you. I definitely see the point in faster. Either way, I appreciate the insight. Thanks!

Comment: If the answer works for you, don't forget to mark it as correct :)

Comment: Okay, thanks for reminding me, still learning this forum.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need a loop to do this. Here is what I did:

```
dates <- data.frame(Date = seq(from = as.Date("2002-06-01"), to = as.Date("2011-09-30"), by = 'day'))

nums = c(98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107)

turning_point_dates <- data.frame(nums, dates = dates$Date[nums])
```